# Webpack 4: How to set up Code Splitting for a library exporting individual modules (akin to Lodash or Office Fabric UI)

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, module, code-splitting

I currently have a large private NPM library which is being consumed by several other teams' apps across the business. At the moment the library is being published as one large single file (like the main lodash file) but this is causing application bundle size to be bloated as some of the applications don't need a large chunk of what is in the library.

So at the moment the apps are importing something like this

```
import { SomeReactComponent, someHelperFunction } from 'my-private-library';
```

What I want to achieve is the library published with individual modules similar to how Lodash, so the above would become:

```
import SomeReactComponent from 'my-private-library/lib/SomeReactComponent';
import someHelperFunction from 'my-private-library/lib/someHelperFunction';
```

I can get Webpack to output output the library in this format using multiple entry points, but what I can't get to work is getting Webpack to split out shared dependencies of each of those modules. So say the files look something like this:

#### src/SomeReactComponent.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

import SOME_CONST_STRING from '../constants';

const SomeReactComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>You are using {SOME_CONST_STRING}</div>
  );
}

export default SomeReactComponent;
```

#### src/someHelperFunction

```
import SOME_CONST_STRING from '../constants';

export default function someHelperFunction() {
  return `This is just an example of ${SOME_CONST_STRING}`;
}
```

My Webpack is outputting the individual files, but it's not splitting out common code in a way that an app can consume the library. So notice above the `SOME_CONST_STRING` which is imported in each of the modules, Webpack is putting this code in both of the exported files.

My Webpack config looks a bit like this (*removed other setting for brevity*)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    SomeReactComponent: './src/SomeReactComponent',
    someHelperFunction: './src/someHelperFunction',
  },
  output: {
    path: './lib',
    library: 'MyPrivateLibrary'
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
  // removed other setting for brevity
}
```

I have tried using the `splitChunks` optimization setting like this

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    SomeReactComponent: './src/SomeReactComponent',
    someHelperFunction: './src/someHelperFunction',
  },
  output: {
    path: './lib',
    library: 'MyPrivateLibrary'
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
  },
  // removed other setting for brevity
}
```

which does chunk the code, but when I try to use the library in an app after doing this I get errors along the lines of (`ERROR in TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function`).

My question is can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible with Webpack? Are there any example out there (as I can't find any) on how to do this?

***Apologies for the example code, as my library is private I'm not able to use real-code examples.***

Comment: Today I ran into this problem myself with the desire to have the same solution as you. [That's what I came up with](https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-code-splitting-library).

Answer (score 0):

Did you get success to achieve what you were trying to achieve in above scenario. I am working on the same use case and was facing similiar issue. After diagnosing it i found it that when we define library then in parsed module webpack add this in **this** object as  `window.myWebpackJsonpMyPrivateLibrary` in minified main chunk which is undefined. if you remove the **library** and **libraryTarget** from webpack then you will not face this issue.

In my case i faced another issue that required chunk(s) are not being loaded when this is used as install dependency in another project.

Comment: Afraid not. I've still not found the answer. I almost achieved what I wanted using RollupJS which seems much better suited at creating ES module libraries.

Comment: So did you try doing this by configuring through rollup? Actually i was also thinking to give it a try ?